# ForEachController is picking duplicate values from regular expression variable results when match count set to -1 when executing with more than 1 user

Tags: foreach, jmeter, performance-testing

Jmeter ForEach controller is picking duplicate values from regular expression variable results when match count set to -1.

```
ThreadGroup

--Req1
--Req2

---RegEx: with Match No. -1 (Debug Sampler shows match count: 40 )

---ForEach Controller

----Http req using ForEach controller's output variable
```

It is picking correctly for single user and when executing with more than 1 user, its picking duplicate values

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does.

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So each thread (virtual user) executes Req2 and Regular Expression Extractor returns 40 variables. So each user has **its own set of 40 variables** and uses the ForEach Controller to iterate them

If you have more than one user and need each user to have it's own variable or set of variables you could:

1. Perform the extraction of these 40 variables with 1 thread somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test)
2. Convert the JMeter Variables into JMeter Properties using [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the code like:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('myVar_matchNr') as int, {
       props.put('myVar_' + it, vars.get('myVar_' + it))
   })

   props.put('myVar_matchNr', vars.get('myVar_matchNr'))
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to access 1st variable where required using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(myVar_1,)}`, 2nd variable as `${__P(myVar_2,)}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Counter is the cause of problem in my request,

```
Track counter independently for each user --> Unchecked, causing the issue
```